# How to get Json Objects inside the Json Array and store it in MySql In php

Tags: php, mysql

I want get Json objects from the json array and store each values in mysql using php.

```
$arr = "[{"fruit":"Apples","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Oranges","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Potatoes","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Tomatoes","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Grapes","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Dhanana","isSelected":false,"number":0}]";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

Using `json_decode`

```
<?php
$arr = '[{"fruit":"Apples","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Oranges","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Potatoes","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Tomatoes","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Grapes","isSelected":false,"number":0},{"fruit":"Dhanana","isSelected":false,"number":0}]';
$data = json_decode($arr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
foreach($data as $k=>$v){
    echo $v->fruit." ".$v->isSelected." ".$v->number."<br>"; //store in db here using value
    print_r($v);
}
?>
```